# Upgrade My PDF Files from Version Using Java

Tags: java, pdf, upgrade

I am currently using Java to get a PDF document and add text using PDFBox to it.

I would like to know how I can upgrade my existing PDFs from version 1.2 to version 1.3 and above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend the iText library http://itextpdf.com/ . It has some very useful PDF manipulating functions.

Comment: i text does the job but if someone does not want to purchase itext they can always mirror the pdf file and have it saved in a new pdf document using PDFBox

Answer (score 1):

The 1.3 version adds features and is backwardly compatible with 1.2 so you would need to recreate it really with a tool which can produce 1.3 output.

If you just want to hack the version number for some reason, you could just edit the version number in the first line of the PDF file (remember it is a binary file so do not edit it in a text editor as this would generally corrupt the file).

Comment: The problem is that we have a reporting system that is currently creating pdf reports in the Version 1.2 and i would like it to be higher then 1.3 since then i can manipulate the pdf using Java and PDFBox

Comment: If PdfBox works with 1.3 it should work with 1.2 as its backward compatible

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the SAP business Objects when creating a PDF file it was not allowing any other program alter the PDF.